# How to make a generic toggle function using state?

Tags: reactjs, toggle, state, setstate

How can I (if it's possible) properly set this generic Toggle function for showing modals and conditional renderings using state?

I got syntax errors with my tries..

```
toggle = (e) => {
let stateTarget = e.target.name;
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: !this.state.?})};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `stateTarget` variable to access the current value from state using flat brackets. For example:

```js
toggle = e => {
    const stateTarget = e.target.name;
    this.setState({ [stateTarget]: !this.state[stateTarget] });
}
```

It's also recommended to use the functional version of `setState`, that way you'll be using the most recent version of the component state, rather than risking using a stale version. You can do this like so:

```js
toggle = e => {
    const stateTarget = e.target.name;
    this.setState(prevState => ({ [stateTarget]: !prevState[stateTarget] }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of closure.

```
toggle = name => e => {
  this.setState(prev => ({ [name]: !prev[name] }));
}
```

And use like this

```
onClick={toggle('name1'))
onClick={toggle('name2')
```

Comment: It worked when I did name => e => ... instead of '=' only. Could you explain this a bit better or/and share some read about it? thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a typo. you are right. It should be name => e =>